# convert string to array and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, cookies

This code allows you to insert an array of variables in a cookie and then modify it.

You need to import jquery.cookie.js http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="include/js/jcookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

This function checks the cookie.

```
//Funzione controllo cookie
function checkcookie() {

    if (typeof $.cookie('cookie') == 'undefined') {
        newcookie();
    }
}
```

This function converts an array into a string and creates the cookie.

```
//Funzione crea cookie
//crea un array e lo trasforma in stringa per il cookie
function newcookie() {
var cookievars = [$.now(),'','','','','','','',''];
    var a = "";
    for(key in cookievars)
    {
        b = cookievars[key]+",";
        a = a.concat(b);
    }
a = a.substring(0,a.length-1);
console.log(a);
$.cookie('cookie', a, { expires: 365 });
}
```

This function gets the string variable into the cookie and converts it into array; modifies the array and converts the string to overwrite the cookie

```
//Funzione modifica cookie
//apre il cookie e recupera la stringa che viene trasformata 
//in aarray, modificata e ritrasformata in stringa per il cookie
function modcookie(idlink) {
    var a = $.cookie('cookie');
    var a = a.split(",");
    for(key in a)
    {
        if (a[key] =='') {
            a[key] = idlink;
            break;
        }
    }

b = "";
for(key in a)
    {
        c = a[key]+",";
        b = b.concat(c);
    }
b = b.substring(0,b.length-1); //rimuove l'ultima virgola ","
console.log(b);
$.cookie('cookie', b, { expires: 365 });
}
```

Someone knows how to do it better?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [code that already works](http:///codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1):

Why not work with JSON serialization?  You can serialize your data to JSON before writing to cookie and de-serialize after reading from cookie and before working with/modifying the data.

Example:

```
function writeJSONCookie(cookieName, data, options) {
    options = options || {};
    $.cookie(cookieName, JSON.stringify(data), options);
}

function readJSONCookie(cookieName) {
    return JSON.parse($.cookie(cookieName));
}

// usage sample
var cookieData = readJSONCookie('someCookie');
// change data
cookieData.property = 'new value';
// persist change
writeJSONCookie('someCookie', cookieData);
```

This can flexibly work to store any kind of object or array you want to an arbitrary cookie.  There is no need to do any of that manual concatenation business you are currently doing.

Now since I have shown you manual way of doing this, let me also point out that the cookie plugin supports automatic conversion of data to/from JSON.  Simply set this following option:

```
$.cookie.json = true;
```

And the usage example above simply becomes (no need for the functions defined before):

```
// usage sample
$.cookie.json = true;
var cookieData = $.cookie('someCookie');
// change data
cookieData.property = 'new value';
// persist change
$.cookie('someCookie', cookieData);
```